# Spring MVC retain error meesage after redirect

Tags: spring-mvc, http-redirect

I have a jsp with 2 input boxes that searches on 2 different scenarios. So , i have two different Get requests mapping to /search1 and /search2 but have created only one POJO for this.
As soon as user submits a search, I check if there is any results for that, and if not i add error message in model and "redirect:"(redirection because if i simply return a page and now make a new search the url will be /search1/search2) to the same basic page.

But everytime i load the page the error message persists. 
Any workaround for this? how do i display the messaeg only on search.

Comment: Could you post your controller code?

Answer (score 1):

Use Flash Attributes.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/

Add `RedirectAttributes` parameter to your controller's handler method.

then `redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("modelAttributeName", "value");`

then redirect

The controller handler that you redirect to should have `"modelAttributeName"` model attribute available to it.

Essentially your a putting a value into session which is removed as soon as it is read on the next request.

Comment: Thanku so much.. Exactly fitted the requirements.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be 
you can use request parameter to pass message id and write utility to read message from properties file using message id in the get request of redirected controller.

Controller 1

```
return "redirect:your_redirection_url?messageId=1";
```

Controller 2 (where redirected)

```
if (messageid != null && !(messageid.equals(""))) { MessageUtility.addMessage(Integer.parseInt(messageid), model, locale); }
```